# Mixing Lookahead and Lookbehind in 1 Regexp

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match first occurrence of `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com")` in some HTML string.

Especially I want to capture the URL of the first `window.location.replace` entry in whole HTML string.

So for capturing URL I formulated this 2 rules:

- it should be after this string: `window.location.redirect("`
- it should be before this string `")`

To achieve it I think I need to use lookbehind (for 1st rule) and lookahead (for 2nd rule).

I end up with this Regex:

`.+(?<=window\.location\.redirect\(\"?=\"\))`

It doesn't work. I'm not even sure that it legal to mix both rules like I did.

Can you please help me with translating my rules to Regex? Other ways of doing this (without lookahead(behind)) also appreciated.

Comment: You do not need any lookarounds. `/window\.location\.redirect\("([^"]*)"\)/` or `/window\.location\.redirect\("(.*?)"\)/`.

Comment: _Note:_ if this is not for one time job and you actually process some javascript, you should not use regex.

Comment: What is the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you wrote is really not the one you need as it matches something very different from what you expect: `text window.location.redirect("=")` in `text window.location.redirect("=") something`. And it will [only work in PCRE/Python](https://regex101.com/r/jO1uZ5/1) if you remove the `?` from before `\"` (as lookbehinds should be fixed-width in PCRE). It will work with `?` in .NET regex.

If it is JS, you just cannot use a lookbehind as its regex engine does not support them.

Instead, use a capturing group around the unknown part you want to get:

```
/window\.location\.redirect\("([^"]*)"\)/
```

or

```
/window\.location\.redirect\("(.*?)"\)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jO1uZ5/2)

No `/g` modifier will allow matching just one, first occurrence. Access the value you need inside Group 1.

The `([^"]*)` captures 0+ characters other than a double quote (URLs you need should not have it). If these URLs you have contain a `"`, you should use the second approach as `(.*?)` will match any 0+ characters other than a newline up to the first `")`.